# swiping multiple elements separately on a same page using hammer.js

Tags: html, hammer.js

I have certain different divs on a webpage and I am using Hammer.js to swipe on these divs. The problem I am facing is that swipe function works on one div at a time, is there a way to swipe multiple div's in one go and the same time if only div is swiped only that should move.

```
     var element= document.getElementById('1');



    var element_2= document.getElementById('2');

  Hammer(element).on("swiperight",function(){



  //console.log(swapID);
//console.log(numberOfTiles);

//document.getElementById( i.toString()).style.backgroundColor = 'green';


var $carousel = $('#'+1+' .swiper-wrapper'),
    currentSlide, nextSlide;
    currentSlide = $carousel.attr('data-slide');
          nextSlide = +currentSlide === 4 ? 1 : +currentSlide +1;
          $carousel.attr('data-slide', nextSlide); 




                      });

Hammer(element_2).on("swiperight",function(){

//console.log(swapID);
//console.log(numberOfTiles);

//document.getElementById( i.toString()).style.backgroundColor = 'green';


var $carousel = $('#'+2+' .swiper-wrapper'),
    currentSlide, nextSlide;
    currentSlide = $carousel.attr('data-slide');
          nextSlide = +currentSlide === 4 ? 1 : +currentSlide +1;
          $carousel.attr('data-slide', nextSlide); 
            });
```

Here is the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/bgevhpa8/

Comment: You have to provide actual code, enough in the question to demonstrate what you're doing and preferably a http://jsfiddle.net working demo that shows the problem.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I have included the fiddle link and re-framed the question, here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/bgevhpa8/